# custom appender plugin not detected by log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, appender

I am trying to create a custom appender for log4j 2.0, but am having issues getting my log4j configuration to recognize the appender. I know log4j 2.0 doesnt support packages in configuration attributes. So I tried, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918810/log4j2-configuration-will-not-load-custom-pattern-converter/24931395#24931395), running the code with plain javac but even then it gives this error:`2015-03-11 18:47:35,281 ERROR Error processing element Test: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2015-03-11 18:47:35,307 ERROR Unable to locate appender test1 for logger`

Here is my custom appender:

```
@Plugin(name = "Test", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public class TestAppender extends AbstractAppender{
protected TestAppender(String name, Filter filter,
        Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, boolean ignoreExceptions) {
    super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@PluginFactory
public static TestAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") String name,
        @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") boolean ignoreExceptions,
        @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
        @PluginElement("Filters") Filter filter) {



    return new TestAppender(name, filter, layout, true);        
}

public void append(LogEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(event.getMessage());
}

}
```

and my config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" >
<Appenders>
    <Test name="test1" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %msg%n" />
        <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" />
    </Test>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="test1" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for any useful input

Answer (score 17):

I added the package containing the  Custom Appender in the Configuration of log4j2.xml before the appenders and it picked up the custom appender with no errors.

```
<Configuration packages="com.yourcompany.yourcustomappenderpackage">
```

I referred this thread - [How to Create a Custom Appender in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j)

Comment: But the packages attribute is not supported in log4j2.0

Comment: are you using the beta version or release ? I used the log4j-2.2.api and core

Comment: This answer is correct.  The packages attribute is supported by log4j2, I use it to perform a triggered rollover strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into docs [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html), you are probably missing annotation processor configuration in your maven compiler plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>log4j-plugin-processor</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <configuration>
        <proc>only</proc>
        <annotationProcessors>
          <annotationProcessor>org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.processor.PluginProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Those same docs say you normally shouldn't need to add this: _"Serialized plugin listing files are generated by an annotation processor contained in the log4j-core artifact which will automatically scan your code for Log4j 2 plugins and output a metadata file in your processed classes. There is nothing extra that needs to be done to enable this; the Java compiler will automatically pick up the annotation processor on the class path unless you explicitly disable it."_