# log4j2 with 3rd party appenders

Tags: java, log4j2, sentry, logentries

I'm trying to set up some third party appenders in a java app (which is a web API) - the appenders are libraries which are added as dependencies.  This is a maven app, and those libraries are Raven (via Sentry) and Logentries. They accept logs and provide GUIs to view them.

Things work fine locally - when run locally logs throughout the app successfully show up in both Logentries and Sentry. The configuration is successfully found and parsed fine in both environments. My `log4j2.xml` config and output when starting the server for both environments is included below.

On the staging environment I'm seeing logs which say `CLASS_NOT_FOUND`, so maybe this is a class path issue? Any ideas?

**config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration status="all">
    <properties>
        <property name="pattern">%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=${env:MODE}] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <console name="console" target="system_out">
            <patternlayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </console>
        <raven name="sentry">
            <dsn>[dsn_here]</dsn>
            <patternlayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <!--to turn down the noise-->
            <!--<ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>-->
        </raven>
        <logentries name="le">
            <token>[token_here]</token>
            <patternlayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <!--to turn down the noise-->
            <!--<ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>-->
        </logentries>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="le"/>
            <appender-ref ref="sentry"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="com.amazonaws" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

**staging environment output when starting the server**

```
Oct 13 20:21:23 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:23,723 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml]
Oct 13 20:21:23 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:23,729 main DEBUG Installed script engines
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,282 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_101, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,283 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 99 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,283 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,285 main ERROR Error processing element raven ([appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,286 main ERROR Error processing element logentries ([appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,288 main DEBUG No scheduled items
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,289 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,303 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,303 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,317 main DEBUG createProperty(name="pattern", value="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=dev] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n")
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,317 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,326 main DEBUG configureSubstitutor(={pattern=%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=dev] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}, Configuration(jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml))
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,327 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,328 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,332 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=dev] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,332 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,366 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,367 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,367 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,381 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(patternlayout(%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=dev] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="console", follow="null", direct="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,381 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,381 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,382 main DEBUG createAppenders(={console})
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,382 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,383 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="le", level="null", Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,383 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,383 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="sentry", level="null", Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,383 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,384 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,384 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,385 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={le, sentry, console}, ={}, Configuration(jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,386 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,387 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,387 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,390 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="com.amazonaws", includeLocation="null", ={console}, ={}, Configuration(jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,391 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,401 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root, com.amazonaws})
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,401 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "le" for logger config "root"
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,401 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "sentry" for logger config "root"
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,402 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml] initialized
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,402 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml]
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,402 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/home/company-dev/app/current/company-server.jar!/log4j2.xml] OK.
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,403 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@531d72ca...
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,403 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,403 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,404 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
Oct 13 20:21:24 dev-company1 java: 2016-10-13 20:21:24,404 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
Oct 13 20:21:45 dev-company1 journal: Suppressed 692 messages from /system.slice/company.service
Oct 13 20:21:45 dev-company1 java: 08:21:45.045 [mode=dev] [cluster-ClusterId{value='57ffecc465bab830ccd6f372', description='null'}-dev-mongo2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Checking status of dev-mongo2:27017
Oct 13 20:21:45 dev-company1 java: 08:21:45.045 [mode=dev] [cluster-ClusterId{value='57ffecc465bab830ccd6f372', description='null'}-dev-mongo2:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=dev-mongo2:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, roundTripTime=9.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=dev-mongo3:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=4.4 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=dev-mongo4:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=1.4 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

**local environment output when starting the server**

```
2016-10-13 16:38:11,696 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml]
2016-10-13 16:38:11,725 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2016-10-13 16:38:12,421 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_102, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2016-10-13 16:38:12,421 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 101 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,422 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,429 main DEBUG No scheduled items
2016-10-13 16:38:12,431 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,448 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,448 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,468 main DEBUG createProperty(name="pattern", value="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n")
2016-10-13 16:38:12,469 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,482 main DEBUG configureSubstitutor(={pattern=%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml))
2016-10-13 16:38:12,482 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,483 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,494 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-10-13 16:38:12,494 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,514 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,516 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,517 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2016-10-13 16:38:12,518 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
2016-10-13 16:38:12,527 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(patternlayout(%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="console", follow="null", direct="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-10-13 16:38:12,528 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2016-10-13 16:38:12,528 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,530 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-10-13 16:38:12,530 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=com.getsentry.raven.log4j2.SentryAppender].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,534 main ERROR appender raven has no parameter that matches element patternlayout
2016-10-13 16:38:12,534 main DEBUG createAppender(name="sentry", dsn="https://229c49d166d34562b819422b438db969:808712a3940b4f838d47b148c57d884e@sentry.company2.com/2?options", ravenFactory="null", release="null", environment="null", serverName="null", tags="null", extraTags="null", filters=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,535 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,535 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-10-13 16:38:12,536 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=com.logentries.log4j2.LogentriesAppender].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,538 main DEBUG createAppender(name="le", token="eb8056e2-f7df-4882-acb1-3048c7006643", key="null", location="null", httpPut="false", ssl="false", debug="false", useDataHub="false", dataHubAddr="null", dataHubPort="0", logHostName="false", hostName="null", logID="null", ignoreExceptions="false", patternlayout(%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [mode=local] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), Filters=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,540 main DEBUG Starting LogentriesManager le
2016-10-13 16:38:12,542 main DEBUG AsyncLogger created.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,543 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,543 main DEBUG createAppenders(={console, sentry, le})
2016-10-13 16:38:12,543 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,544 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="le", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,544 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,545 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="sentry", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,545 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,545 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,546 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,547 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={le, sentry, console}, ={}, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,549 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,550 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="console", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,550 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,552 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="com.amazonaws", includeLocation="null", ={console}, ={}, Configuration(/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-10-13 16:38:12,552 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2016-10-13 16:38:12,553 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root, com.amazonaws})
2016-10-13 16:38:12,554 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml] initialized
2016-10-13 16:38:12,554 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml]
2016-10-13 16:38:12,555 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml] OK.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,555 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@7d0587f1...
2016-10-13 16:38:12,555 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,556 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,556 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,556 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,556 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2016-10-13 16:38:12,556 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,557 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,557 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@7d0587f1 OK
2016-10-13 16:38:12,628 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@19c65cdc
2016-10-13 16:38:12,628 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@74bf1791
2016-10-13 16:38:12,631 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,631 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,632 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,632 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,633 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=*'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,633 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,633 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,634 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2016-10-13 16:38:12,637 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
2016-10-13 16:38:12,640 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
2016-10-13 16:38:12,641 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
2016-10-13 16:38:12,643 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
2016-10-13 16:38:12,644 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.amazonaws
2016-10-13 16:38:12,646 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=console
2016-10-13 16:38:12,646 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=le
2016-10-13 16:38:12,647 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=sentry
2016-10-13 16:38:12,651 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,652 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,653 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI /Users/justin/dev/company/company-server/target/classes/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@74bf1791) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-10-13 16:38:12,653 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,655 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@74bf1791] started OK.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,679 main ERROR Recursive call to appender sentry
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.RavenFactory - Attempting to find a working Raven factory
2016-10-13 16:38:12,725 main ERROR Recursive call to appender sentry
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.RavenFactory - Attempting to use 'RavenFactory{name='com.getsentry.raven.DefaultRavenFactory'}' as a Raven factory.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,730 main ERROR Recursive call to appender sentry
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] INFO  com.getsentry.raven.DefaultRavenFactory - Using an HTTP connection to Sentry.
2016-10-13 16:38:12,866 main ERROR Recursive call to appender sentry
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.Raven - Adding 'com.getsentry.raven.event.helper.HttpEventBuilderHelper@74f5ce22' to the list of builder helpers.
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.Raven - Adding 'com.getsentry.raven.event.helper.ContextBuilderHelper@40238dd0' to the list of builder helpers.
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.RavenFactory - The raven factory 'RavenFactory{name='com.getsentry.raven.DefaultRavenFactory'}' created an instance of Raven.
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] DEBUG com.getsentry.raven.event.EventBuilder$HostnameCache - Updating the hostname cache
04:38:12.012 [mode=local] [main] INFO  com.company.server.companyServer - company-server starting
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're launching it locally and on staging? I feel like this must be a classpath issue, which is more common if you're using a fancy application server.

Comment: the staging instance is administered using AWS opsworks which is using chef recipes. ultimately after the instance is configured and the appropriate revision of the java jar is retrieved, it's launched using `/usr/bin/java -jar /home/<%=node[:company][:user]%>/app/current/company-server.jar`

Comment: What is the output of: `jar tf $YOUR_JAR | grep getsentry`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jayceekay/48d13fd2f903403e81e06433246bb44a

Comment: Very odd, I assume there is an application server built into that jar? Which one?

Comment: it's mostly a home grown thing using jetty, here's the pom: https://gist.github.com/jayceekay/838f9e4a005fb5204ca3b3e24f82c232. 

the pom also tells the story of how i battled with log4j2 being imported multiple times, hence the exclusions. i'm not really sure if they're 100% right, i just know that it made it the errors/warnings stop and made it behave how i would expect it to.

Comment: Can you try this out? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29111780/11958

Comment: I think it's saying to try `<Configuration packages="com.getsentry.raven.log4j2">` somewhere near the top of your `log4j2.xml`?

Comment: argh, that was it. it's even on their docs, not sure how i missed that. for both, this is what i needed: `packages="com.getsentry.raven.log4j2,com.logentries.log4j2"`

thanks a ton!

Comment: Brett, did you wanna submit a formal answer?

Comment: It's OK, I work with ehfeng so if that was the solution feel free to accept it. :)

Comment: awesome, thanks for the great support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<Configuration packages="com.getsentry.raven.log4j2">` somewhere near the top of your log4j2.xml

(posting this for completeness, though Brett answered this in the comments)